# Correctly remove old items in Sharepoint Calendar

Tags: calendar, delete, recurring-events

I have a standard Sharepoint Calendar, which users regularly make entries to.
As the number of items constantly grows, I need to remove old events. There's no business need for events that are older than today, but there's an issue with recurring events (E.g., there's an event in the past, but it's recurrences will end in the future). So, the problem is how to delete past calendar entries, but only if all their recurrences have already also occured.
I tried to solve this with Expiration policy, but in this case the whole chain is removed.
Is it at all possible without programming?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with SharePoint Designer workflows in SharePoint 2010.  The workflow can start when the items is added or created and then pause until a specified date hits.  You could use the item's end date or you could add an "expiration date" column to go off that has some default values.